# Git hooks for automation

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, gradle

I have below requirements,

1. In commit message we have to capture some of the mandatory data like FileName, user story, description etc and later these will be stored in db. Can we create conditional tags so that developer can give either userstory, CR# or defect# based reason for which fix is required?
2. We have spring boot gradle project. Here we have to automate the static code analysis and Junit Analysis through Pre Commit Hook. Can we write these hooks in java?

Please share some examples.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For your commit messages, there is a customary way to include various pieces of data, which is the trailer system.  These are lines of the following format:

```
Signed-off-by: A U Thor <author@example.com>
Fixes: 1234
```

It is possible for you to extract data from this either by parsing the commit message yourself or by using `git interpret-trailers`.  This may be able to be done in JGit if you want to do it in Java, but it may or may not have built-in support for parsing trailers.  It is strongly recommended that you use the exact same parsing technique that Git does if you need to implement it yourself to avoid creating compatibility problems.

The general rule with hooks on Unix is that they must be either a binary or a script executable by the operating system.  Usually Java JARs don't meet that requirement, so you'll probably want to write a shell script wrapper that invokes your Java code.  However, this will be very slow, since you'll need to start a full JVM every time.

In addition, you should be aware that, as [the Git FAQ outlines](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks), hooks are not an effective tool for controlling policy:

> It’s common to try to use `pre-commit` hooks (or, for commit messages, `commit-msg` hooks) to check these things, which is great if you’re working as a solo developer and want the tooling to help you. However, using hooks on a developer machine is not effective as a policy control because a user can bypass these hooks with `--no-verify` without being noticed (among various other ways). Git assumes that the user is in control of their local repositories and doesn’t try to prevent this or tattle on the user.

Therefore, if you want to have effective controls, you need to perform these actions on your CI server.  You can still provide hooks for developers who wish to use them, but you cannot rely on them being run.  The FAQ also mentions this as another reason why you don't want to mandate hooks:

> In addition, some advanced users find `pre-commit` hooks to be an impediment to workflows that use temporary commits to stage work in progress or that create fixup commits, so it’s better to push these kinds of checks to the server anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info..